# How to access magento database in outside

Tags: magento2

I am working with a project on Magento e-commerce, now I want to access the Magento database in the yii2 framework. anyone help me

Comment: Why do you wanna access database ?? Its not good practice to share database among different systems. You can use the API end points to get and put whatever data you need.

Answer (score 0):

I am not why you need to access the Magento 2 database, Suggest to use `REST API` https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/index.html.

You can find database credentials at `magentoProjectDirectory/app/etc/env.php` files.

Comment: sir, I am already using REST API. but I didn't get the custom attributes field. I got the only limited field.

Comment: which API you are using

Answer (score 0):

## Warning - It is not good practice to access the database out of the Magento System.

### But if you really want to do it then refer below:

### Method 1:

To access a database, you first need to connect to it by creating an instance of yii\db\Connection:

```php
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example2',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);
```

Once you have a database connection instance, you can execute a SQL query by taking the following steps:

- Create a `yii\db\Command` with a plain SQL query;
- Bind parameters (optional);
- Call one of the SQL execution methods in `yii\db\Command`.

The following example shows various ways of fetching data from a database:

```php
$posts = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post')
            ->queryAll();
$post = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=1')
           ->queryOne();
$titles = $db->createCommand('SELECT title FROM post')
             ->queryColumn();
$count = $db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post')
             ->queryScalar();
```

With Bind Parameters:

```php
$post = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=:id AND status=:status')
           ->bindValue(':id', $_GET['id'])
           ->bindValue(':status', 1)
           ->queryOne();
```

**Note**:

When configuring a DB connection, you should always specify its **Data Source Name (DSN)** via the [[yii\db\Connection::dsn|dsn]] property. The format of DSN varies for different databases.

### Method 2:

Because a DB connection often needs to be accessed in different places, a common practice is to configure it in terms of an *application component* like the following:

```php
'db' => [
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
   ....
],
'otherDb' => [
   'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
   'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example2',
   'username' => 'root',
   'password' => '',
   'charset' => 'utf8',
],
```

And use it like `Yii::app()->otherDb`

Comment: $servername = "xxx";
            $database = "xxxx";
            $username = "xxxxx";
            $password = "xxxxx";
            $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }
            echo "Connected successfully";
            mysqli_close($conn);    
sir i would like to connect magento db in outside this way.is it ppossible

Comment: laravel api .is it possible

Comment: But Yii has it's own way of communicating to the database. Why not use that and connect to the database, instead of relying on mysqli_connect()?

Comment: Also, Yii does not support mysqli, it uses PDO. So use PDO instead of mysqli_connect. Refer here - https://gist.github.com/Mathanagopal97/06c6991efa4578d90ce3eea4068ca102